# How to add multiple constructors to a struct?

Tags: c#, struct, constructor

I have the following code:

```
struct test {
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public test(int a) {
        this(a, null);
    }

    public test(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Where I would like to have two different constructors for the `test` struct, one where I only need to pass in `a` and another where I can pass in both `a` and `b`.

This code does not work, as it fails with a few errors:

For the `public test(int a) {` line:

> Field 'test.a' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller

> Field 'test.b' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller

And for the `this(a, null);` line:

> Method name expected.

> The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields have been assigned

Comment: Two mistakes: `int` can't be `null`, you'd have to pass `0`. And `test(int a) { this(a, null);` should be `test(int a) : this(a, 0) {`

Comment: int can't be `null` try to put `0`.

Comment: Sorry you're right about the int null thing, I was just whipping together a quick example. In my real use case I have a property that can be null, so just mistranslated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct test {
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public test(int a) : this(a, 0) { }
    
    public test(int a, int b = 0) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

You can't assign null to int. Also your variable names are ambiguous. You can use an optional parameter to achieve what you're looking for. Or chaining constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
struct Test 
{
    public readonly int a;
    public readonly int b;

    public Test(int a) : this()
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = 0;
    }

    public Test(int a, int b) : this()
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

an alternative is to use an optional parameter with one  constructor

```
    public Test(int a, int b = 0) : this()
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
```

or instead of `0` to use `default(int)`, or just `default`

```
    public Test(int a) : this()
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = default(int);
    }
```

The `: this()` call is added by Microsoft when the *create constructor* tool is used so I have added it here. I think it is just to remind the reader of the code that space in the stack is allocated first and then the fields are assigned.

I also added the `readonly` keyword because mutable structures are evil and to emphasize the requirements the fields need to be all defined before the constructor ends.

Or you can always use one constructor from another constructor

```
    public Test(int a) : this(a, 0)
    { }
```